# PHPExcel returns empty PDF file

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I have a project based on PHPExcel and I want to have two output types: .xls and .pdf. The .xls output is working great, no problem with that, but as soon as I want to output the result as a .pdf file, it's not working... the final .pdf file is a 0B file, so total empty.

Here is the PDF writer (tcPDF, located in the /var/www/tcpdf directory) inicializaion part at the beginning of the file:

```
/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once 'scripts/PHPExcel.php';

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../../../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'scripts/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'tcpdf';
$rendererLibraryPath = $rendererLibrary;
if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
        $rendererName,
        $rendererLibraryPath
    )) {
    die(
        'Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        PHP_EOL .
        ' as appropriate for your directory structure'
    );
}
```

Here comes the manipulation functions, so skip these...

This is the output section:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

if($_GET['format'] == 'xls'){

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="bs-export.xls"');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}

if($_GET['format'] == 'pdf'){

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="bs-export.pdf"');

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'PDF'); 
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

Can someone help me out here what could be the problem?

Thank you very much!!

**EDIT:** I didn't notice it had some variable name errors... so I corrected the

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'PDF');
```

line to :

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
```

After this the PDF file isn't 0B site anymore, but its't still a blank page... The XLS output is okay.

**EDIT2:** Very strange... This returns a total blank page too:

```
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_HTML($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save("pdf-test.htm");
```

Comment: Enable error logging, and watch out for memory or timeout errors

Comment: $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_PDF($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'PDF'); - use one or the other, but using both is meaningless and unnecessary overhead

Comment: I found the error: "PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter() must be an instance of PHPExcel, null given, called in /var/www/xxx.php on line 1630 and defined in /var/www/scripts/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php on line 132"

Comment: $objPHPExcel !== $objPHPexcel - case sensitivity.... use only one of the writer creator statements, and ensore that the correct $ObjPHPExcel variable is passed to that

Comment: I changed it to "$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');" it had variable name error. After this the PDF document isn't 0B now, but it's still total empty, so it's just a blank page.

Comment: PDF works by generating HTML using the HTML Writer, and then passing that to the appropriate rendering library: test that the HTML is generated correctly (using the HTML writer), then test with a simply script to manually feed that to tcPDF (independently of PHPExcel) and see if that does render a file

Comment: Can you provide me some example code how to do this? PS.: I see that you are on Codeplex's PHPExcel as well. Does it help if I open a topic there too?

Comment: Anyone found a solution?

Comment: @VORiAND hi, i'm sorry for this question im a newbie. I would like to know where do you store the PDF Writer? i've searched in the class folders but didn't find this path:  /var/www/tcpdf

Comment: @MarkBaker I have this exact problem (Non 0B blank PDF generated, XLS well generated). I tried what you said in your comment and the HTML is generated correctly and I can use tcPDF to print the HTML but the result is not good (cells are smaller in the PDF than in HTML and everything looks messy).  Since this worked, what else can I check or try in order to get the phpExcel writer to generate the pdf? Thanks!

Comment: Consider looking at other PDF rendering engines; PHPExcel provides wrappers for 3 choices, and some are better than others